# How to declare array with custom indices, in Unity JavaScript?

Tags: arrays, indexing, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm looking for a way to store variables of same type in an array, and access them by their names. Like in PHP you do:

```
$array = array();
$array['first member']=$var1;
$array['another member']=$var2;
// so on
```

I want to do a similar thing in Unity3D's JavaScript. I have AudioClip variables, currently used like this:

```
#pragma strict

var Audio_Goal:AudioClip;
var Audio_Miss:AudioClip;
var Audio_Saved:AudioClip;


function PlaySound_Goal()
{   
    audio.PlayOneShot(Audio_Goal);  
}

function PlaySound_Miss()
{   
    audio.PlayOneShot(Audio_Miss);  
}
```

of course this requires one function per audioclip, which is ugly.

I want to do it like this:

```
function PlayAudio(audioname:String)
{
    audio.PlayOneShot(AudioArray[audioname]);
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use something like a dictionary:

```
#pragma strict
import System.Collections.Generic;
var AudioArray = new Dictionary.<string,AudioClip >();

// add to dict
AudioArray["one"] = AudioClip.Create(/**/); //see AudioClip.Create(...) for arguments

// play from dict
audio.clip = AudioArray["one"];
audio.Play();
```

Comment: that's true but unfortunately unity can't serialize them. It's one of the biggest problem for me, because I use them a lot. Any tips for that?

Comment: Serialize the Keys and Values separately, then LINQ them together at runtime with ToDictionary.

Comment: @Jessy I'd be curious to see the LINQ version in unityscript.  I do basically the same thing, just with an uglier for loop.  I'm not sure if it's my version (3.5) or syntax but something like `myList.ToDictionary (x=>x,x=>dummyValue);` says that x is an unexpected token.  Tried with delegates as well but I'm afraid I'm not a unityscript guru.

Comment: That's fine; UnityScript is worthless.  I'm putting the code in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
var myAudioClips: AudioClip[];

function Start() {
    // Your stuff...
}

function PlayAudio(audioname:String)
{
    for (var myClip in myAudioClips) {
        if (audioname.Equals(myClip.name)) {
            audio.PlayOneShot(myClip);  
        }
    }

}
```

And then add all of your clips in the array by dragging them using the editor.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Enumerable.Zip>, but because it's not available in UnityScript, I think this is the best you can do:

```
var names : List.<String>;
var clips : List.<AudioClip>;

var keyFunc = function(kvp : KeyValuePair.<String, AudioClip>) kvp.Key;
var valueFunc = function(kvp : KeyValuePair.<String, AudioClip>) kvp.Value;
var dictionary = names.Select( 
    function(name, index) new KeyValuePair.<String, AudioClip>(name, clips[index]) 
).ToDictionary(keyFunc, valueFunc);
```

I don't know why you need to store the Funcs.  This code compiles, but won't run:

```
var dictionary = names.Select( 
        function(name, index) new KeyValuePair.<String, AudioClip>(name, clips[index]) 
    ).ToDictionary(function(kvp) kvp.Key, function(kvp) kvp.Value);
```

Report it as a bug if you want.  I don't want to, because I don't think the devs need to waste any more time on this language.